# How do I print a particular value from my json requests?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to get a particular variable within the response of my request. How can I retrieve my response?

```
import requests
import json

url = "XXXXXX"

payload = json.dumps({
  "userName": "XXXXXX",
  "systemCode": "XXXXXX"
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
print(type(response))
```

print out the response and try to access its contents

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first step is to actually fetch the json.  You don't have to convert the response text to json yourself.  `jsondata = response.json()`

Comment: When you POST JSON you should use the *json* keyword and **not** the *data* keyword. How do you know if the response is valid if you don't check the HTTP status code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `response.json()`

You can learn more from [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_response.asp)

> json()        Returns a JSON object of the result (if the result was written in JSON format, if not it raises an error)